# How to align nav menu with a search bar and dropdown tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made a nav bar with a search form, a few links, and a link that has a dropdown to more links.

**However, I can't seem to find a way to get everything on the same line of the navbar.**

Here is the output right now: [My HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M7Y1.png)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text], .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the dropdown menu is out of order with the other links. Is there any way to align the 'dropdown' link with the other links with the dropdown links inside the dropdown tab until you hover over it? I have been stuck on this all day so any ideas or suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example align the dropdown button and search bar:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: white;
    }

    .topnav .search-container {
      float: right;
    }

    .topnav input[type=text] {
      padding: 6px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
    }

    .topnav .search-container button {
      float: right;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-right: 16px;
      background: #ddd;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .topnav .search-container button:hover {
      background: #ccc;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav .search-container {
        float: none;
      }

      .topnav a,
      .topnav input[type=text],
      .topnav .search-container button {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
      }

      .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="padding: 14px 16px;">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not give any styling to the drop-down part, that's the reason it was not aligned.

Here I have made some changes to HTML part and added the required CSS. Hope This Helps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav a,
  .topnav input[type=text],
  .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}


/* dropdown part CSS*/

.dropdown {
  float: left;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: Blue;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</body>
```